# Django App works in local server, but when pushed to heroku it only shows static html

Tags: python, django, heroku

Thanks in advance. I am totally new to this and I am following the Django Girls tutorial for a blog app. Please let me know what else I should include to help answer the question!

The website just shows a static header "Django Girls Blog" with a font imported from google, and underneath it shows the post models we have created.  It all works perfectly when run from the local server, but when I deploy it to heroku it only shows the header in times new roman.

There are no errors when I deploy it.

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you comitted the `Procfile` file with the suggested contents?

Comment: Have you tried running `./manage.py collectstatic` to collect your static assets?

Comment: Is there a different process for committing the Procfile than other files in the project?  My Procfile currently contains: web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi  @Cristik

Comment: @AronYsidoro, I just about tried to, but it says it will replace my current staticfiles file, is that correct?

Comment: @ShelleyHoover: are your Heroku workers configured, i.e. do you have at least one worker? Also please add the output that you receive when you push the code (paste it in the question). About the static files, if you see that you lost some of your files after `collectstatic`, you can revert the changes from git

Comment: @ShelleyHoover Just add `heroku logs` output here. We are happy to help you,

Comment: @RajaSimon Thank you!  It was pretty long, so I just included the last bit. I've tried a bunch of different things, so the section i grabbed probably doesn't capture where it went wrong, but I struggling to interpret the log output.  2015-05-05T12:31:53.278579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stati
c/admin/img/icon_calendar.gif" host=shelleyhoover.herokuapp.com request_id=9cd1b
82f-7719-4c97-bcf5-0b107b56f26b fwd="162.193.196.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms ser
vice=1ms status=304 bytes=110

Comment: @ShelleyHoover no actually it doesn't help to solve it... If `foreman start` works correct then heroku will also works ...